# vue UnwrapRefSimple<T> generics type can't assignable to T at reactive

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typescript-generics

I have created a hook function and want to reuse it in other places:

```
import { ref, Ref, reactive } from 'vue'

const useSelectAarray = <T>(items: T[]) => {
  const selectItem: Ref<T|null> = ref(null)
  const options = reactive([...items])
  const select = (key: string, value: any) => {
    const trigger = options.find((item: { [index: string]: any }) => item[key] === value)

    if (typeof trigger !== 'undefined') {
      selectItem.value = trigger
    }
  }

  return {  
    selectItem,
    select,
    items: options
  }
}
```

But at `selectItem.value = trigger`, I get an type error `Type 'UnwrapRefSimple<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'。`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 25):

```
const selectItem = ref<T>(null) as Ref<T?>
```

see: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2136

Comment: It happened to me while passing `ref<T[]>([])` as an argument of a function. Typescript was complaining on another argument that had no link to this ref! Your solution worked: specifying `ref<T[]>([]) as Ref<T[])` fixed the problem.

Comment: Sure let's ignore the problem and let's use "as" each time there is a Typescript error...